# How can I save selected Excel worksheets as separate csv files, overwriting existing csv files with no dialogue?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that saves ALL the worksheets in a workbook to csv files.
What I would like to do instead is to save only certain selected worksheets (selected by worksheet name).
I would also like to leave the original excel file unchanged and still open.
I would like to write over any pre-existing csv files automatically (no warning dialogue boxes)

Here is the code I am using so far:

```
Sub ExportWkshtCSV()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
 CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook

      SaveToDirectory = "V:\whereIsavetheCSVs\"

      For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
      Next

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: It saves ALL the sheets in the workbook, I want to select only some worksheets to save.  I end up in a CSV file instead of the original excel sheet (which I wanted to stay in) and when I run it the second time I get the dialogue box that asks if I want to replace the csv files that already exist in my folder for each csv file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this.

```
Const WsNames As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet14,Sheet9"
Dim Ws          As Worksheet

For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        If InStr(1, WsNames, .Name, vbTextCompare) Then
            .SaveAs SaveToDirectory & .Name, xlCSV
        End If
    End With
Next Ws
```

Watch out for shorter names that might be included in longer ones. If this is an issue you may have to loop through all names to find a match. It's very fast. No problem in the execution. It would just take 3 extra lines of code to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code I ended up using

```
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat

SaveToDirectory = "V:\WhereIsavedIt\"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Const WsNames As String = "Nameofsheet,Nameofothersheet"
Dim Ws          As Worksheet

For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        If InStr(1, WsNames, .Name, vbTextCompare) Then
            .SaveAs SaveToDirectory & .Name, xlCSV
        End If
    End With
Next Ws
  
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```